# XML not deserializing to correct class, and not serializing with xsi:type attribute after

Tags: c#, xml

In the following snippet, I'm trying to deserialize XML that has type attributes on `Animal` records identifying them as either `Cat` or `Dog`, both of which inherit from `Animal`.

When deserialized, these records all appear as `Animal`.

Then, when attempting to serialize the object (after deserialization), the `xsi:type="Dog"` and `xsi:type="Cat"` does not appear in the XML.

I'm not sure if this is due to how I've decorated the classes or in my serializer/deserializer implementation.  Preferring if possible a solution in the class rather than the serializer/deserializer wrapper methods.

Code:

```
using System;  
using System.IO; 
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization; 

namespace sandbox
{
    public partial class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            string xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                "<OuterClass xmlns=\"http://myschema.com/\">" +
                "   <Animals>" +
                "      <Animal xmlns:xsi=\"http://myschema.com/\" xsi:type=\"Dog\">" +
                "         <Name>Watson</Name>" +
                "         <Height>10</Height>" +
                "         <Weight>10</Weight>" +
                "         <Paws>4</Paws>" +
                "         <Woof>True</Woof>" +
                "      </Animal>" +
                "      <Animal xmlns:xsi=\"http://myschema.com/\" xsi:type=\"Cat\">" +
                "         <Name>Hermy</Name>" +
                "         <Height>10</Height>" +
                "         <Weight>10</Weight>" +
                "         <Paws>4</Paws>" +
                "         <Meow>True</Meow>" +
                "      </Animal>" +
                "   </Animals>" +
                "</OuterClass>";

            OuterClass data = null;

            try
            {
                data = DeserializeXml<OuterClass>(xml);
                foreach (Animal curr in data.Animals) Console.WriteLine(curr.Name + ": " + curr.GetType().ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(SerializeXml(data));
            Console.ReadLine(); 
        }

        public static T DeserializeXml<T>(string xml)
        {
            XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml))) 
                return (T)xmls.Deserialize(ms); 
        }

        public static string SerializeXml(object obj)
        { 
            XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType()); 
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    xml.Serialize(writer, obj);
                    byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
                    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "OuterClass", Namespace = "http://myschema.com/", IsNullable = true)]
    public class OuterClass
    { 
        [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Cat)), XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Dog)), XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Animal))] 
        public Animal[] Animals { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType(TypeName = "Cat")]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Animal", Namespace = "http://myschema.com/", IsNullable = true)]
    public class Cat : Animal
    { 
        public bool Meow { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType(TypeName = "Dog")]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Animal", Namespace = "http://myschema.com/", IsNullable = true)]
    public class Dog : Animal
    { 
        public bool Woof { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlInclude(typeof(Cat))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Dog))]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Animal", Namespace = "http://myschema.com/", IsNullable = true)]
    public class Animal
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public int Weight { get; set; }
        public int Paws { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Watson: sandbox.Animal       <-- should be sandbox.Dog
Hermy: sandbox.Animal        <-- should be sandbox.Cat
?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OuterClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://myschema.com/">
  <Animals>
    <Animal>                 <-- missing xsi:type, object missing 'Woof' 
      <Name>Watson</Name>
      <Height>10</Height>
      <Weight>10</Weight>
      <Paws>4</Paws>
    </Animal>
    <Animal>                 <-- missing xsi:type, object missing 'Meow'
      <Name>Hermy</Name>
      <Height>10</Height>
      <Weight>10</Weight>
      <Paws>4</Paws>
    </Animal>
  </Animals>
</OuterClass>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in your example:

- the model does not match xmls
- every Animal element overrides xsi namespace
- boolean values are not supported for serialization

Please find additional details about problems below:

## 1. model does not match xmls

When you specify [XmlArrayItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute?view=netframework-4.8) `XmlSerializer` will use type name as element name, or you can change it by providing [ElementName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.elementname?view=netframework-4.8) explicitly. If you annotate array property with `XmlArrayItem` you'll get the following output:

```
Console.WriteLine(SerializeXml(new OuterClass { Animals = new Animal[] { new Cat(), new Dog() } }));

<OuterClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://myschema.com/">
  <Animals>
    <Cat>
      <Height>0</Height>
      <Weight>0</Weight>
      <Paws>0</Paws>
      <Meow>false</Meow>
    </Cat>
    <Dog>
      <Height>0</Height>
      <Weight>0</Weight>
      <Paws>0</Paws>
      <Woof>false</Woof>
    </Dog>
  </Animals>
</OuterClass>
```

If you don't annotate, you'll get output with type defined by xsi:type attribute:

```
<OuterClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://myschema.com/">
  <Animals>
    <Animal xsi:type="Cat">
      <Height>0</Height>
      <Weight>0</Weight>
      <Paws>0</Paws>
      <Meow>false</Meow>
    </Animal>
    <Animal xsi:type="Dog">
      <Height>0</Height>
      <Weight>0</Weight>
      <Paws>0</Paws>
      <Woof>false</Woof>
    </Animal>
  </Animals>
</OuterClass>
```

In this case you must add `XmlInclude` attribute to the base class.

## 2. every Animal element overrides xsi namespace

http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance is a special namespace defined in [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Instance_Document_Constructions) that helps serializer to know what type is in the XML element. 
In your input xml, each Animal element overrides this namespace with a custom http://myschema.com/ so when serializer meets `xsi:type="Cat"` it has no idea what it means. Wikipedia is a good starting point to read about XML namespaces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace

## 3. Boolean values in XML

[W3C defines boolean data type as ‘true’, ‘false’, ‘0’, and ‘1’](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/helloworld/2009/04/03/workaround-to-deserialize-true-false-using-xmlserializer/) so you'll get an exception if you'll deserialize boolean with value '**T**rue'. You may find workaround options online but I suppose that your input XML is malformed and you need to lowercase boolean values in XML.

Comment: Hi, on (1) I removed the annotation ```XmlArrayItem``` and it still did not add ```xsi:type```.  With ```XmlArrayItem```, both show as ```Animal``` rather than ```Dog``` and ```Cat```.  

On (2), when I changed to the schema URL you supplied, with the ```XmlArrayItem``` annotation, each object was reflected as either ```Dog``` or ```Cat```.  Removing the ```XmlArrayItem``` caused it to properly reflect each object as ```Animal``` with the ```xsi:type``` annotation.

On (3), thank you, yes that's an oversight on my part.  Thanks for your thorough response!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the classes correctly :

```
            OuterClass outerClass = new OuterClass()
            {
                Animals = new Animal[] {
                    new Dog() { Name = "Watson", Height = 10, Weight = 10, Paws = 4},
                    new Cat() { Name = "Hermy", Height = 10, Weight = 10, Paws = 4}
                }
            };
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this example, I'm deserializing from XML and then re-serializing, so the code doesn't actually construct the object itself.

Comment: You can serialize my results and then compare to your xml to see if they match.  Then correct the differences.

Comment: If my deserializer were working correctly, it would have deserialized to exactly what you show in your response.  I was looking for specifics on how to annotate/decorate the XML classes so that it would deserialize that way.  Illia's answer got me there.  Thanks

Comment: Not if you were missing "Cat" and "Dog".  Since you did not get cat and dog then you serialized the two animals as class Animal while my code a have the class Dog and Cat.

Comment: The XML in the example include ```type=Cat``` and ```type=Dog```.  That was the base of the question.  So yes, I agree, it didn't deserialize as Cat and Dog for some other reason, which caused it to not serialize as Cat and Dog.